# how to align 3 columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 columns and I want each column to be aligned left.  I am able to do this using flexbox but it seems like a lot of overhead.  Is there a better approach?

```css
span {
  display: block;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center">
  <div>
    <span>High</span>
    <span>Low</span>
    <span>Mean</span>
    <span>Median</span>
    <span>Mode</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>=</span>
    <span>=</span>
    <span>=</span>
    <span>=</span>
    <span>=</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    
    <span>100</span>
    <span>80</span>
    <span>94.29</span>
    <span>100</span>
    <span>100</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The "overhead" seems to be coming less from the styling and more from the fact that these are three separate tables.  Is that part necessary?  If the goal is for this data to be presented as three columns in one table, why not structure it like that?

Comment: There isn’t really any sense in which any of those tables are tables. Taken together, the first and the last would seem to legitimately be a table, or maybe a grid,  and the = are just styling. Are you stuck with that HTML structure or are you allowed to change it?

Comment: You don't have 3 columns. You have 3 tables inside one div. I have never seen anyone spread one table over 3 tables like this in my entire life but if you want to you can set a css property of `table {  flex: 1; }`. This is shorthand for `flex-grow : 1; flex-shrink : 1; flex-basis : 0;` and you will get your desired result.

Comment: hi, thanks for the feedback.  I removed the table structure as it's not germane to the problem.  Still seems like a lot of overhead.  Is there an easier or more efficient way to align or tab to desired column.  Something like: MEAN [tab] = [tab] 100

Comment: and I do have 3 columns.

Comment: I see the update. Setting the parent `div` element to `{display:flex; flex-direction:row}` and then setting your 3 `div` columns to `{display:flex; flex:1}` is semantically clear and a simple approach. Have you considered just using one table with 3 columns?

Comment: I have just seen your altered structure. The semantics just are not correct. Please consider what a screen reader user would get from this - there being no link between for example 'high' and '100'. I have put a suggested restructuring in an answer. If you need different styling, let me know.

Comment: Your code currently does not left-align anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a correct HTML structure where we can actually read the data then you can rely on a table layout

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}
.container p {
  display: table-row;
  word-spacing: 8px; /* space between "=" and numbers*/
}
.container p span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 12px; /* space between the text and "=" */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p><span>High</span> = 100</p>
  <p><span>Low</span> = 80</p>
  <p><span>Mean</span> = 94.29</p>
  <p><span>Median</span> = 100</p>
  <p><span>Mode</span> = 100</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use `<table>` if OP has tabular data and you display it in table formatting

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like a table of two columns of data which when presented are joined by the = signs.

This snippet has one table with each row having the left and right values in its two cells.

The = are provided by a before pseudo element.

```html
<style>
  td:last-child::before {
    content: '= ';
  }
</style>
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>High</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Low</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Mean</td>
      <td>94.29</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Median</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Mode</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This structure would seem to make more sense to screen readers too as the data is linked logically.

Comment: pseudo elements are not well interpreted by screen readers see [here](https://accessibleweb.com/question-answer/how-is-css-pseudo-content-treated-by-screen-readers/)

Comment: @jQueeny - correct, but the = is not actually data, the fact that these are rows in a table links them. They can be added in a cell if deemed needed of course.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a [Description List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) is an appropriate element to use here?

```css
dl {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

dd {
  margin: 0
}

dd:before {
  content: "= ";
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>High</dt><dd>100</dd>
  <dt>Low</dt><dd>80</dd>
  <dt>Mean</dt><dd>94.29</dd>
  <dt>Median</dt><dd>100</dd>
  <dt>Mode</dt><dd>100</dd>
</dl>
```